# Are there any mirrored LEGO bricks?

Tags: piece-information

I recently built LEGO Creator 5770: Lighthouse Island which features a clever trick to build the lighthouse's lantern, using stickers on on a Slope Brick 2x2 and Slope Top 1x2x2/3:

[image: Stickers on slopes]
Step 54 from [Lighthouse Island Instruction Manual 1/3](http://cache.lego.com/bigdownloads/buildinginstructions/4649557.pdf)

It works reasonably well, but I'd like something better. Are there any official mirrored (or prismatic, but this seems even less likely) LEGO bricks?

Comment: I have updated my answer to include the [first official mirror LEGO piece](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/750/132).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Bricklink search for chrome pieces](http://www.bricklink.com/browseList.asp?q=&itemType=P&catID=&colorID=22)

**Gold 2x4**

[image]

**Duplo: Chrome 2X4**

[image: duplo]

Answer (score 11):

The Detective’s Office & Barber Shop (10246) includes the [first mirror in a LEGO set](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UoQMpqjdPTQ#t=90). It was released 1st January 2015.

According to [New Elementary](http://www.newelementary.com/2014/12/review-lego-10246-detectives-office.html), the piece is the same size as 1x4x6 windows, it comes in a bag with stickers to protect the sides from scratches and the part ID is [20193](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=20193).

[image]

---

Alternatively, there are also [highly polished bricks](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/243/132) available in chrome and gold that reflect more light then others. These bricks tend to be rare and expensive.

There is a non-purist solution that works well using metalic paper or tin foil which can be found in craft stores and supermarkets respectively. The material is relatively cheap, flexible, can be as small or large as you like and provides a decent reflective surface. You can use double sided tape to stick the material onto slopes or you can hold them in place using bricks.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

My little sister had a lot of LEGO Belville, which has some glossy silver bricks and parts:
[image: belville]

see the bin and the decoration-bricks on top of the grids - but I never saw or owned "normal" bricks or plates of this color which could be used to build a mirror or something.

Answer (score 5):

LEGO [have produced prisms](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?q=prism). Here's one type:

[image: Prism]

Answer (score 5):

There is the '[Chrome Silver Dish 2 x 2 x 2/3 Light Reflector](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=x85)' available from [BrickLink](http://www.bricklink.com/search.asp?itemID=2863&colorID=22).
[image]

This piece was available in [many sets](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=x85&in=S), one of which was the [3801 - Ultimate Accessory Set](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?set=3801-1) for MindStorms where it is used as a reflector around a '[White Electric, Light Brick 1 x 2 with Single Side Light](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=6035)' element.

Answer (score 4):

There are also chrome bricks, such as the LEGO lightsaber hilt, that is hard to see your face on, but they are reflective.

Comment: Bigger chromed pieces were available in a [Special Edition Naboo Starfighter](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=10026-1). Shiny!

Answer (score 3):

One other mirror piece that hasn't been listed is the Mirror of Erised in [4721-1: Hogwarts Classrooms](https://brickset.com/sets/4721-1/Hogwarts-Classrooms).

[image: set image]

It too is a sticker, on another piece, in this case a clear window.

[image: sticker image]

On the front, the sticker is reflective, with screen printing for the characters over it. On the *back side* however (the side with the adhesive), it is all reflective.

[image: mirror back]

It's not perfect, it has a bit of a texture, but it is pretty reflective.

Answer (score 2):

I had some [gold bars](http://lego.wikia.com/wiki/Gold_Bar) from a LEGO City police set.

They are ten 1x2 Metalic Gold tiles in [this LEGO Agents set](http://lego.wikia.com/wiki/8630_Mission_3:_Gold_Hunt):

[image: Agents set picture]

I will also add that these bricks' reflections aren't diffuse - that is, they're as reflective as the back side of an iPhone, so they'd probably work pretty well as mirrors.

Comment: I have this set and the gold bars are the kind that are not very reflective.

Comment: @Ambo100 Oh, really? Mine are reflective. At least, I hope they still are. Haven't seen 'em for two years. :( So are yours like the LEGO Indiana Jones golden idol's material, then?

Answer (score 2):

There is at least one Clikits set that contains an actual mirror: [7504 Friendship Frame / Mirror](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?S=7504-1)

The actual part is [Clikits Mirror Insert 4 x 4, fits Frame clikits011](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=clikits197) which is a bit large for use in the Creator Lighthouse but is an official LEGO mirror part.